# Delete a file on mouse click(single or double)

Tags: script

I want to delete a file or folder whenever I try to open that file. Is there any script available to do like this?
The purpose of this is security.

If I double click on a folder it should ask for a password and if I enter wrong password, it should delete the folder.

Comment: OS? This is highly OS/GUI shell dependent. Also what tool would accept the password and try a decrypt? What would it do when password is good? Would first fail delete the file? Better hope you check caps lock then. I think any wedge in file handling would remove security than you are getting from this